# Proving that the fraction field of a $k[x,y]/(f)$ is isomorphic to $k(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

> Let $f \in k[x,y]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$, $k$ is a field, and there exist $a,b\in k$ such that $f(a,b) = 0$. I'm trying to prove that $\mathsf{frac}(k[x,y]/(f))$ is isomorphic to $k(t)$, the field of rational functions with single variable.

What I know:

$f$ is irreducible and so its prime, so the ring $k[x,y]/(f)$ is an integral domain, so the fraction field is just the quotient of its elements. But I am stuck at this point. The only thing I can think of is finding some embedding from $k[x,y]/(f)$ into $k(t)$, then $\mathsf{frac}(R)$ would be contained in $k(t)$ and go from there.

Any hints would be appreciated...

Comment: If $k=\mathbb R$ and $f=x^2+y^2$ then the fraction field doesn't seem isomorphic to $\mathbb R(t)$.

Comment: That's the problem statement as given to me by my professor. All of us including our TA are stuck. What even do the elements in this ring look like?

Comment: The fraction field of $\mathbb R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ is $\mathbb R(y)[x]/(x^2+y^2)$, and therefore the elements of it are of the form $a(y)+b(y)x$  with $a(y),b(y)\in\mathbb R(y)$. This is a field, but not a purely transcendental extension of $\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb R(t)$ is.

Comment: I received a hint from professor. apparently it involves mapping x/y to t from the quotient ring to k(t).

Comment: If one follows the hint then in my example $t=x/y$ is algebraic over $\mathbb R$ since $t^2+1=0$. (I still support the opinion that your claim is wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

The fraction field of $R=\mathbb R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ is $K=\mathbb R(y)[x]/(x^2+y^2)$, that is, $K=\mathbb C(y)$, and this is not a purely transcendental extension of $\mathbb R$ (why?). It follows that $K\not\simeq\mathbb R(t)$.