# Function field $K(C)$ isomorphic to $K(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $C$ be a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ over a field $K$ defined by an equation of the form
$f: y^2 - x^3 - ax^2$ with $a \in K$.

I want to show that the function field of $C$ is isomorphic to $K(t)$.

The function field $K(C)$ is the fraction field of $K[C] = K[x,y]/(f)$.

Since we're quotienting by $f$, I think that every $g \in K(C)$ can be written as $a(x) + b(x)y$, where $a,b \in K(x)$. Therefore $K(C) \cong K(x)[y]/(f)$.
(This coincides so far with a comment on a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606435/proving-that-the-fraction-field-of-a-kx-y-f-is-isomorphic-to-kt?noredirect=1&lq=1).)

However, I don't know how to get the last part. 
Is there an obvious isomorphism I'm overlooking, or do I have to use the equation of the curve somewhere explicitly?
(I've shown that there exists a singular point on $C$, but I don't see any use of this fact.)

Comment: Try $t=y/x$. From $f=0$ you can solve $t^2=x+a$. From there on it should be easy.

Comment: Basically, the curve has a double point at the origin, and this is the usual blow-up resolving the singularity.

Comment: A geometric interpretation of Jyrki Lahtonen's idea is that this gives a rational parameterization of your curve, which shows that your curve is birational to a line and thus has function field $K(t)$.